# Excel-VBA combo box value on form load

Tags: excel, forms, vba, box

I have a VBA form which is used to enter data on a sheet. I am currently coding the form so as it will load any data already existing in the sheet back into the form.

For simple text strings it works perfectly.

e.g.

```
ReqSetup.ReqText = Application.Worksheets("Req Sheet").Range("F11").Value
```

However, I have some combo boxes, that on the form, when they are selected will enter a number in the corresponding cell.

Fail 1. - Run Time Error 380 - Invalid property value.

```
    ReqSetup.MinPerKgCB = Application.Worksheets("Req Sheet").Range("C27").Value
```

Fail 2.

```
    Dim MinPerKg As Range
    Set MinPerKg = Application.Worksheets("Req Sheet").Range("C27")

    ReqSetup.MinPerKgCB = MinPerKg
```

I'm obviously doing something really simple wrong but I can't work out what it is!!

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

> I have some combo boxes, that on the form, when they are selected will
>   enter a number in the corresponding cell

Then you'd need to do the opposite of your code attempt, i.e.:

```
 Worksheets("Req Sheet").Range("C27").Value = ReqSetup.MinPerKgCB.Value
```

That you'd better wrap inside a check that any combobox value is actually selected :

```
With ReqSetup.MinPerKgCB
    If .ListIndex <> -1 Then Worksheets("Req Sheet").Range("C27").Value = .Value
End With
```